# I can't get the inverse Laplace transform in terms of the unit step function

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

I tried this:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[-((-6.5 - 3.25 s - 5.5 s^2 + 0.5 s^3 + 
      s^4)/((2 + s) (1 + 0.5 s + s^2) (1.5 + s + s^2))), s, t] // 
   Simplify // ComplexExpand // Simplify
```

In this way I get the following:

```
0.714286 E^(-2. t) - 1.71429 E^(-0.5 t) Cos[(1.11803 + 0. I) t] + 
 3.19438 E^(-0.5 t) Sin[(1.11803 + 0. I) t]
```

which is similar to the answer I want:

$ [0.7143 e^{-2t}-1.7145 e^{-0.5t}cos(1.25t)+3.194 e^{-0.5t}sin(1.25t)]u(t) $

I have tried with FullSimplify, Apart, TrigReduce, ExpToTrig and I have not got the answer in terms of the UnitStep function.

I will appreciate any suggestion to get the answer I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be that The unit step is implied in the result, so it is not needed unless there is an ambiguity. You can see this from

```
LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t], t, s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[1/s, s, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So Mathematica returned `1` and not unitstep.  If you want a unit step in the result, just multiply the result by unit step. But it is assumed that the result of the inverse Laplace transform is for `t>=0` (because Laplace transform works from `t>=0` by definition.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But still the answer does not match because there are complex numbers. If I add // Chop the complex numbers are removed but it differs a bit.

Comment: If you use inexact numbers like `6.5` in your input, you will have an inexact result.

Answer (score 1):

It can be computed as the impulse response. (I also rationalized it to get the exact result.)

```
tfm=TransferFunctionModel[Rationalize[-((-6.5-3.25 s-5.5 s^2+0.5 
     s^3+s^4)/((2+s) (1+0.5 s+s^2) (1.5+s+s^2)))],s];
or=OutputResponse[tfm,DiracDelta[t],t][[1]]//Simplify
```

> [image]

Comment: InverseLaplaceTransform[
  Rationalize[-((-6.5 - 3.25 s - 5.5 s^2 + 0.5 s^3 + 
     s^4)/((2 + s) (1 + 0.5 s + s^2) (1.5 + s + s^2)))], s, 
  t] // Expand. I used Rationalize that I saw in your answer, thanks.